# python n-ary tree for directories

Tags: python, tree

I'm searching for an answer in python to represent an n-ary tree for directories.
I think an N-ary tree for folders is a good example. Here is my code:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.children = []

n = Node(sys.argv[1])

def walktree(top): # recurse from "/top/"

    X = [] # clear record
    for f in os.listdir(top):
        pathname = os.path.join(top,f)
        mode = os.stat(pathname)[ST_MODE]
        if S_ISDIR(mode):  # It's a directory
            X.append(pathname)  #
            walktree(pathname)  # recursion
    X.sort()
    n.add_child(X)
```

MY QUESTION IS:

1. Is this code correct?
2. How to fill given Node of N-ary tree
3. How to traverse constructed N-ary tree

Answers to 1,2,3.

```
def dirwalk(top): # build an n_ary tree 
    n = Node(top) # ONE Node per folder 
    for f in os.listdir(top): # loop over the current dir
        pathname = os.path.join(top,f) # dir + fname
        mode = os.stat(pathname)[ST_MODE]
        if S_ISDIR(mode):  # It's a directory
            ptr = dirwalk(pathname) # go down 
            n.add_child(ptr) # add pointer to node
    return n # return Node

def traverse(n): # traverse buildt tree
    for p in n:  # loop over children
        print p.data  
        traverse(p.children)
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: you do know that you could just use the `os.walk()` method and it would work like this as well?

Comment: @IT: Actually, `os.walk` is a lot more general than that. But of course we could build this `walktree` function on top of it.

Comment: @NiklasB. Yeah, i actually made something similar for a recent project, and i just grabbed the directories from the os.walk() and put them in a dictionary according to its root, which is what i think the OP is asking, however im not quite sure.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the pythonic way to do this would be to just use nested lists. You could represent a directory by the tuple `(subdirs, files)` where both `subdirs` and `files` are lists, `subdirs` containing further tuples, `files` being a list of filenames.

Example for construction, incorporating namedtuple as suggested by Niklas B:

```
import os, os.path
from collections import namedtuple

Directory = namedtuple('Directory', ['path', 'subdirectories', 'files'])

def walktree(path):
    dirs = []
    files = []
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, f)):
            dirs.append(walktree(os.path.join(path, f)))
        else:
            files.append(f)
    return Directory(path, dirs, files)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly trivial to implement using [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk):

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.files = []
        self.folders = {} 
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s: files: %s, folders: %s' % (self.name, self.files, self.folders)

def find_node(top_node, name):
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    result = top_node
    path = name.split(os.sep)[1:]
    for path_comp in path:
        result = result.folders[path_comp]

    return result

import sys, os
tree = Node(sys.argv[1])
for root, folders, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    parent_node = find_node(tree, root)

    for folder in folders:
        parent_node.folders[folder] = Node(folder)

    for file in files:
        parent_node.files.append(file)

print tree
```